# Android internet speed test

Tags: java, android, performance, bandwidth

I am developing a speed test app like [OKLA app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.zwanoo.android.speedtest&referrer=utm_source%3Dstnet%26utm_medium%3Dmobile%26utm_campaign%3Dstnet) (http://www.speedtest.net/).

I've been trying to get bandwidth rate with the most common approach:

1. Get the time before downloading.
2. Download some file for some time X.
3. Get the time after downloading and the total size downloaded.
4. Calculate speed from TIME and BYTES RECEIVED.

Also, I execute this in two different threads at the same time because is required to saturate de connection to achieve good results.

This approach works very well on PC environment with this JAVA code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

public class TestVelocidad {

static long totalBytesReceived = 0; //
static long startSample; 
static long endSample ; 
private static final long TIME_FOR_DOWNLOAD_MILISECONDS = (long) 10000.0;      
private static final long MILI_TO_NANO = 1000000; 

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {


    try{
        final ExecutorService service;
        String downloadFileUrl100MB = "http://cachefly.cachefly.net/100mb.test";


        startSample = System.nanoTime();

        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
        FutureTask futureTask_1 = new FutureTask(new SpeedTestThread(downloadFileUrl100MB));
        service.execute(futureTask_1);
        FutureTask futureTask_2 = new FutureTask(new SpeedTestThread(downloadFileUrl100MB));
        service.execute(futureTask_2);

        service.shutdownNow();
        long result1 = (Long) futureTask_1.get();
        long result2 = (Long) futureTask_2.get();

        endSample = System.nanoTime();



       long timeSpent = (long) endSample-startSample;
            long totalBytesReceived = result1 + result2;
            System.out.println("Time of threads: " + timeSpent/1000000000.0   + " seconds " + "\nbytes received: " + (totalBytesReceived) );
            double calculatedSpeed;
//            long finalTimeSpent ;
//            finalTimeSpent = (long) ((TIME_FOR_DOWNLOAD_MILISECONDS * MILI_TO_NANO - diff));
            calculatedSpeed =  SpeedInfo.calculate(timeSpent, totalBytesReceived).megabits;
            System.out.println("Velocidad calculada: " + calculatedSpeed   + " mbps" );

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}


class SpeedTestThread implements Callable<Long> {

private String url = new String("");
private static final long TIME_FOR_DOWNLOAD_NANOSECONDS = (long) 10000000000.0;
private static final long MILI_TO_NANO = 1000000;
private long bytesThread;

public SpeedTestThread(String urlToDownload){
    url = urlToDownload;
}

public void run() {


}

@Override
public Long call() throws Exception {


    System.out.println("FileDownload " +  " File to download: " + url );
    InputStream stream = null;
    long startCon = System.nanoTime();
    URL urlToDownload = null;
    try {
        urlToDownload = new URL(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    URLConnection con = null;
    try {
        con = urlToDownload.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    //Tiempo de acceso al archivo.
    long connectionLatency = (System.nanoTime() - startCon)/MILI_TO_NANO;
    System.out.println("Connection latency = " + connectionLatency + "");

    con.setConnectTimeout(5000);

    try {
        stream = con.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long startNano = System.nanoTime();



    int currentByte = 0;
    try {

        while ((currentByte = stream.read()) != -1 ) {
            bytesThread++;
            if ((System.nanoTime() - startNano) > TIME_FOR_DOWNLOAD_NANOSECONDS){
                System.out.println("Time");
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Thread bytes received:  " + bytesThread);
    return bytesThread;
}
}



class SpeedInfo {
public double kilobits = 0;
public double megabits = 0;
public double downspeed = 0;
private static final double BYTE_TO_KILOBIT = 0.008;
private static final double KILOBIT_TO_MEGABIT = 0.001;

/**
 * 1 byte = 0.0078125 kilobits
 * 1 kilobits = 0.0009765625 megabit
 *
 * @param downloadTime in miliseconds
 * @param bytesIn      number of bytes downloaded
 * @return SpeedInfo containing current testVelocidadThread
 */
public static SpeedInfo calculate(final long downloadTime, final long bytesIn) {
    SpeedInfo info = new SpeedInfo();
    //from mil to sec
    System.out.println("Bytes transferidos: " + bytesIn + "Tiempo de descarga: " + downloadTime/1000000000);
    double time = downloadTime;
    double byteIn1 = bytesIn;
    double division = (double)(byteIn1 / time);
    double bytespersecond = ((division) * 1000000000);
    double kilobits = bytespersecond * BYTE_TO_KILOBIT;
    double megabits = kilobits * KILOBIT_TO_MEGABIT;
    info.downspeed = bytespersecond;
    info.kilobits = kilobits;
    info.megabits = megabits;
    return info;
}
}
```

The problem is when I run this on a Android application, I had ***good results on phones with more processing and memory capacity***, but ***poor results on phones with lower capacity***.

Any good ideas to achieve good results on most android's phones?.

Comment: First I was thinking that you are saving the file, which it appears you don't. Second thing i could come up with, is you are counting the bytes you are loading. you could just ask for the size of the File you are about to load like 'conection.getContentLength();'  So your while loop would be empty. Just take Time before and after Download

Comment: Probably, you're loading everything into memory and Garbage Collector starts to freak out (especially on low end devices). Another thing. FutureTask runs asynchronously, so you'll have advantage in multi-threaded environment

Comment: I've tested a different approach with better results. As you said @DanielBo, now I download the entire file (1 MB / 500 KB files) and took de time before and after. This approach produce much better results.

Comment: On the other side, I dropped out the Future Task thing, as you said @Sparrow_ua,  this caused me some problems. Now I just execute "n" times and calculate the max and avg speed, SYNCHRONOUSLY.

Comment: @EstebanCacavelos Does this code works in from marshmallow devices??

Answer (score 0):

try to download the file with java **nio** rather than java **io**

java io transfer the file first to memory which make the performance poor on low end devices

while java nio using channels you can transfer the file to storage which will make the performance same on all devices approximately

use this code :

```java
len = out.getChannel().transferFrom(readableByteChannel , seekPos , Long.MAX_VALUE);
```